# Why do old variables keep reappearing in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

Every time I select a new variable, about a hundred appear from an old project.

For example, I click "yearcol" from my saved variables. ALL of my past variables reappear on the right.

I have tried "clearvars" "clear" and "delete".
[image]
Thanks for helping!

Comment: can you explain `Every time I select a new variable, about a hundred appear from an old project`? Maybe use screenshots?

Comment: here's an example. i start a brand new script. I call a saved variable so i can look at it, plot it, or add it to my script. suddenly, all of the variables that you see on the right pop up, even if i deleted or cleared them a month ago.

Comment: I suspect all those unwanted  variables are stored in your `yearcol.mat`. Is that the case?

Comment: you can use `data = load('yearcol.mat')` to validate

Comment: Unless specific variables are specified, [`save`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html) defaults to saving the entire workspace. Both `save` and [`load`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html) support explicitly choosing variables, and `load` also allows you to specify an output in order to save all of the inputs to a self contained [structure](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/structures.html)

Comment: No, I did not save the workspace. The variables on the left that I have saved are the ones that I want to keep. The ones that keep appearing in the workspace on the right are old variables that I deleted a long time ago. These are variables from probably a month ago that keep appearing.

Comment: MATLAB doesn't have a mind of its own. It's doing exactly what you tell it to, which is load the variables in `yearcol.mat`. If you want to continue to not believe what the documentation is telling you, then type `whos -file yearcol.mat` and see exactly what we're saying, which is all of those variables being in that file.

Comment: yearcol is an array with a bunch of dates for the year 2015. i selected a random variable to show what my problem is. the variables on the right will appear regardless of which variable i choose to load, even if i make a new variable and load it, the old workspace will reappear.

Comment: This is not MATLAB going crazy, but a clear misunderstanding of how things work. The MATLAB PATH has nothing to do with variables in memory, only with functions and files being accessible. A MAT-file is not a variable, it is a file that contains all variables in the workspace at the time you created it, unless you specify which variables to save; the file name has nothing to do with the name of any variables inside, it is simply a name you choose. Read the answer below again, slowly, then do as @excaza asked you above: `whos -file yearcol.mat`.

Comment: Otherwise, from a new MATLAB session, type `load yearcol yearcol`. That will load only the `yearcol` variable from the `yearcol.mat` file.

Comment: Okay. So to clear the mat files, do I simply delete all of them and the workspace issue will resolve?

Comment: If you delete all those files, you will also lose all the data you saved. I simply recommend that you don't double-click on the MAT-files, and load the data in using either `data = load('yearcol.mat')`, then find the values within the fields of `data`, or using `load yearcol.mat yearcol` if you know the name of the variable(s) within the MAT-file that you want to load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most likely had many variables in the Workspace, let's call them 'A', 'B', and 'C', and wanted to save one of them, so you went

```
>> save A
```

and that created a file called `A.mat`.

Then later, you want to look at variable `A` so you went

```
>> load A
```

And suddenly you have all of your variables 'A' and 'B' and 'C' back in your workspace.

As per the doc for [save](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html), the syntax `save something` will create a file called `something.mat` containing **all** of the variables in your workspace at the time you do the save.  And similarly, `load something` will load **all** of the variables in `something.mat`.

You either want to re-save your one variable using the syntax

```
save filename variablename
```

which will save only the variable `variablename` in the file `filename.mat`.  Then you can just use `load filename` and since `variablename` is the only variable in that file, that's what you'll load.

Or, you can use your exist file along with

```
load filename variablename
```

which will load just the variable `variablename` from the file.

Comment: I did save a few variables, but not the ones on the right that keep appearing. I have deleted those several times. They must be saved in memory somewhere, or else they would not appear every time I close and reopen matlab.

Comment: Yes, they are saved "in memory somewhere", that memory is called a .mat file, and you are loading the data from that .mat file.  MATLAB is not magically creating the data.

Comment: Thank you for the help Phil, but this happens regardless of what variable I am uploading. Even if I create a random variable, say just the numbers 1-10, in a completely new + blank script and empty workspace, and then load it, the 1-10 array variable will appear amidst all the variables you see on the right.